# Spring Data Mongodb: Updating documents

Tags: spring, mongodb

I am currently trying to figure out how to update documents in MongoDb via Spring Data. Of course, there is mongoTemplate.updateFirst and so on. But consider this:

```
User u = mongoTemplate.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(s)), User.class);
if (u == null) throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user " + s + " does not exist");
Session.setCurrentUser(u);
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(s)), new Update().inc("logincount", 1), User.class);
```

... query a user, on null throw a exception, if found increment logincount by 1. Works perfectly. But is this the right way? Do I have to query for the user *again*? Can't I modify the object and re-save it?

Comment: Similar Issue and resolution can be found at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733781/mongodb-updatefirst-method-usage/25735785#25735785

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the upsert semantics.

See the answer in this post: [MongoDB and upsert issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490205/mongodb-and-upsert-issue/10494130)

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid the extra query by doing something like:

```
WriteResult result = mongoTemplate.updateFirst(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(s)), new Update().inc("logincount", 1), User.class);
if (result.getN() != 1) {
   throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user " + s + " does not exist");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're up for entity in and out kind of using the template just do the following:

```
User user = template.findOne(query(where("id").is(id)), User.class);
// manipulate object
template.save(user);
```

You also might wanna have a look at the repositories as they don't require you to formulate the queries actually.