# MongoDB UpdateFirst Method Usage

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoTemplate's UpdateFirst() to update the inner document. But the update operation is failing.

my Mongo Collection Structure:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("540dfaf9615a9bd62695b2ed"),
"_class" : "com.springpoc.model.Awards",
"brand" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "Brand1",
        "descr" : "Desc1"
    }
],
"name" : "Award1",
"narname" : "Nar1"
```

}

Java Code:

```
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(
query(where("name").is("Award1")), 
Update.update("brand.$.descr", "Desc2"),
Awards.class);
```

Award Class Structure

```
public class Awards {

private String id;
List<Brand> brand = new ArrayList<Brand>();
private String name;
private String narname;
```

Brand Class Structure

```
public class Brand {
private String name;
private String descr;
```

Any suggestions on how to update the document "Brand.Name" to new value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use operator `$` in update portion, you have to explicitly write `that array` in the query portion. So,

```
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(
query(where("name").is("Award1")), 
Update.update("brand.$.descr", "Desc2"),
Awards.class);
```

should be

```
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(
query(where("name").is("Award1"))
.and("brand.name").is("Brand1"), // "brand" in "brand.name" is necessary, others according to your requirement
Update.update("brand.$.descr", "Desc2"),
Awards.class);
```

If you know the position of element in array, `$' is unnecessary, you can try like this:

```
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(
query(where("name").is("Award1")), 
Update.update("brand.0.descr", "Desc2"), // 0 is the index of element in array
Awards.class);
```

Same way to handle `name` field.

Comment: This works fine. 
Mistake i had was the AND condition in my query was missing.
Also i am able to update the same using combination of FINDONE and SAVE .

Comment: @karthik damu, Perhaps `using combination of FINDONE and SAVE` will produce another issue that is not atomic.